# How to get the action performed in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

What I want to achieve in this question is if I made any update/delete/insert in 1 of my table it should insert that record into 1 of the table for the logs purpose

I have 1 table as test. Suppose If I insert the below row in my table test, it should fire a trigger and insert a row in my another table which is  logs

**test**

```
Id  |   Name    |   Location        
1   |   Test    |   America
```

**log**

```
ID  |   updatetime              |   Action      
----------------------------------------------------------      
1   |   2017-04-06 16:51:18.190 |   Insert
```

And same if I delete or update any thing under action it should have delete or update respectively

```
ID  |   updatetime              |   Action      
----------------------------------------------------------      
1   |   2017-04-06 16:51:18.190 |   Insert  
1   |   2017-04-06 16:51:18.190 |   Delete
```

I have created a single trigger

```
create trigger abc 
on test
after insert, update, delete
as
begin
    declare @id int

    select @id = i.id from inserted i

    insert into log values (@id, GETDATE())
end
```

From the above trigger I am able to get the ID and updatetime, But how to get the action column like what action has been performed how to achieve that. Can anyone have a clue

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your statement affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and/or `Deleted` pseudo tables will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @id = i.id FROM Inserted i` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @Red Devil for which MySQL version does this works because I am getting a syntax error for the "after insert, update, delete" statement only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Create the next approach for Determining which action happens:-

```
DECLARE @Action as char(1);
    SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                         AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                        THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                        THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                        THEN 'D'  -- Set Action to Deleted.
                    END)

-- For Getting the ID
if  @Action = 'D'
select @id=i.id from DELETED i
else -- Insert or Update
select @id=i.id from INSERTED i
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed your code is excellent but I have 1 issue, when I am running the delete query on test table, in my logs table entry is created but in ID column it is showing NULL

Comment: @RedDevil, Because you are selecting form `inserted` , select from `deleted` instead.

Comment: But then if I try to insert or update then its coming as NULL

Comment: so use the both (`inserted` & `deleted`), my answer is updated.

Comment: This is awesome, it works like the way i wanted thanx alot @Ahmed

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader for which MySQL version does this works because I am getting a syntax error for the "after insert, update, delete" statement only.

Comment: @Amarja the question is related to MS SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: Okay... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the action was caused by an INSERT, there will be no rows in the DELETED psuedo table.

If the action as caused by a DELETE, there will be no rows in the INSERTED pseudo table.

If neither of the above is true, then it was an UPDATE because an UPDATE inserts rows into BOTH the INSERTED and DELETED tables.

Of course, there is the occasional "4th condition" where something was executed but no rows were affected and you'd like to simply "Short Circuit" the trigger and leave it without executing any part of it.

All that makes the "Trigger Action" really simple to determine...

```
--===== Shortcircuit any zero-row activity because there will be no changes to record.
     IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN
;
--===== Determine the type of trigger action
DECLARE @Operation CHAR(1);
 SELECT @Operation    = CASE
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM DELETED)  THEN 'I'
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM INSERTED) THEN 'D'
                        ELSE 'U'
                        END
;
```

You could probably combine the CASE determination in the DECLARATION of the variable but that frightens some people, so I didn't offer it that way.

This is a part of "KISS"... "Keep It Super Simple".

And, yes... you could change the "TOP 1 1" to just * but that also seems to get people and automatic code checkers upset.